# NSMutableArray + NSEnumerationConcurrent memory errors

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

So, I'm reading this up on SO and some answers suggests that `NSMutableArray` is not `thread-safe`, but I failed to find a correct answer to a problem I'm seeing.

Take this stripped-down code as a bare example:

```
  __block NSDictionary *remoteMediaFilesKeyedByRemotePath = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:remoteFiles forKeys:[remoteFiles valueForKey:@"remotePath"]];
  __block NSMutableArray *changes   = [NSMutableArray array];

  [localFiles enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(ABSMediaFile *localFile, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    ABSMediaFile *existingRemoteFile = remoteMediaFilesKeyedByRemotePath[localFile.remotePath];
    if (existingRemoteFile != nil) {
      [changes addObject:existingRemoteFile];
    }
  }];
```

When I try to run it, the app perform some operation in threads and then bombs out on the `addObject` line:

`malloc: *** error for object 0x102177438: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.`

Can anyone clarify if I'm better off using fast enumeration alone (single thread) or if is there a way to fix the above code?

I guess placing a mutex in the cycle kinda defeat the purpose of concurrent enumeration in first place.

OSX 10.9, Xcode 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation does state for `NSEnumerationConcurrent` that:

> ...the code of the Block must be safe against concurrent invocation.

Your block relies on a shared resource (and only that), as such I don't think it's worth trying to make this concurrent. As you've mentioned, `NSMutableArray` is inherently thread unsafe, and adding a mutex within the block makes the concurrent operation worthless.

As such, I recommend using fast enumeration, as so:

```
__block NSDictionary *remoteMediaFilesKeyedByRemotePath = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:remoteFiles forKeys:[remoteFiles valueForKey:@"remotePath"]];
__block NSMutableArray *changes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (ABSMediaFile* localFile in localFiles) {
    ABSMediaFile *existingRemoteFile = remoteMediaFilesKeyedByRemotePath[localFile.remotePath];
    if (existingRemoteFile) {
        [changes addObject:existingRemoteFile];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSArray *enumeratedArray = @[@(1), @(2), @(3), @(4), @(5)];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    dispatch_semaphore_t addSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

    [enumeratedArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                      usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // my concurrent operation
        if ( 0 == ([obj integerValue] % 2) )
        {
            // mutable containers is NOT thread safe, need synchronize add or remove operation
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(addSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            [array addObject:obj];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(addSemaphore);
        }
    }];
    // not need for ARC
    //dispatch_release(addSemaphore);
```